# I am getting the error:"UnsupportedOperation: read"

Tags: python, pickle, file-handling

```
import pickle

#writing into the file

f = open("essay1.txt","ab+")

list1 = ["Aditya","Arvind","Kunal","Naman","Samantha"]

list2 = ["17","23","12","14","34"]

zipfile = zip(list1,list2)

print(zipfile)

pickle.dump(zipfile,f)

f.close()

#opening the file to read it 

f = open("essay1","ab")

zipfile = pickle.load(f)

f.close()
```

and output was :

```
runfile('E:/Aditya Singh/Aditya Singh/untitled3.py', wdir='E:/Aditya Singh/Aditya Singh')
<zip object at 0x0000000008293BC8>
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "E:\Aditya Singh\Aditya Singh\untitled3.py", line 21, in <module>
    zipfile = pickle.load(f)

UnsupportedOperation: read
```

Comment: Why do you use mode `ab` to open the file?

Comment: Could the filename be wrong? You wrote essay1 but it looks like it should be essay1.txt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot the file extension `.txt` in the line where you tried to open the file and also you opened it in *append* mode, which is why the returned object does not have `read` or `readline` methods (required by `pickle.load`). I also suggest to use the [`with` keyword](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#with) instead of manually closing the file.

```
import pickle

#writing into the file

with open("essay1.txt","ab+") as f:
    list1 = ["Aditya","Arvind","Kunal","Naman","Samantha"]
    list2 = ["17","23","12","14","34"]
    zipfile = zip(list1,list2)
    print(zipfile)
    pickle.dump(zipfile,f)

#opening the file to read it
with open("essay1.txt", "rb") as f:
    zipfile = pickle.load(f)

for item in zipfile:
    print(item)
```

Output:

```
<zip object at 0x7fa6cb30e3c0>
('Aditya', '17')
('Arvind', '23')
('Kunal', '12')
('Naman', '14')
('Samantha', '34')
```

Answer (score 0):

do you have essay1 file? or essay1.txt?

this is trying to open without extension.

```
f = open("essay1","ab")
```

so fails to read.

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues with your code:

- You're opening the file to write and not to read.
- You're using different filenames for reading and for writing.

Here's a version that works:

```
import pickle

#writing into the file
f = open("essay1.txt","wb")
list1 = ["Aditya","Arvind","Kunal","Naman","Samantha"]
list2 = ["17","23","12","14","34"]
zipfile = zip(list1,list2)
print(zipfile)
pickle.dump(zipfile,f)
f.close()

#opening the file to read it 

f = open("essay1.txt","rb")
zipfile = pickle.load(f)
print(zipfile)
f.close()
```

Comment: @AdityaSingh If the answer solved your problem, consider accepting it by clicking the tick on the left side.